# How to send a file to an upload button in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I send a file to the browser in a headless selenium session (as opposed to clicking on an "upload" button)?

For example, how do I add a file to a form like this without using the gui:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases there is an input element with type file there, so you can directly send your file path to it.
For example if your file path on the disk is `C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.png` your code will be:

```
file_path = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.png"
upload_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
upload_element.send_keys(file_path)
```

Comment: great!  I would advise against using "input" as a variable name though so that it doesnt override the built-in input function.